# Angular 6 Routing ngOnInit not called

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular 6 application, I have created a route to redirect to the `ClosureFormComponent` as in below code:

```
export const closureRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'closure', component: ClosureFormComponent }
];
```

In a confirmation dialog component, on button's click I navigate to the component using route:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
export class ConfirmationDialogComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onContinueClick() {
        this.router.navigate(['/closure']);
    }

}
```

And below is the component, I am navigating to:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CaseServices } from '../../services/case-services.services'
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-service-closure',
    templateUrl:'closure-form.component.html'
})
export class ClosureFormComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private zone: NgZone, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, private caseFormDataService: CaseServices) {

    }

    getClosureFormData() {
        this.caseFormDataService.loadClosureFormData(1, '15', 1);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            console.log('closure form loaded');

            this.route.data.subscribe(() => {
                console.log('closure form loaded route');
            });
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
        });
    }
}
```

Issue is that ngOnInit() (ClosureFormComponent )is not getting fired and no console statement is logged. After searching I assumed it could be zone related issue but still no luck!.

**Edit**: Weird for me is that component (html) gets displayed in the browser but no statements in console. Not able to get why is it so ?

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
onContinueClick() {
    this.router.navigate(['/closure']);
}
```

It should be

```
onContinueClick() {
    this.router.navigate(['closure']);
}
```

`navigate()` is a relative path routing

Comment: What about the view, is it displaying the new component after navigate?

Comment: Put console.log() directly inside the `ngOnInit` instead of `ngZone`. Then it works?

Comment: Please try to remove all injections from constructor and just put `console.log()` directly inside the `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
onContinueClick() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/closure');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to not use `NgZone`

When you say "ngOnInit() (ClosureFormComponent )is not getting fired", did you mean if you put console.log() inside your constructor it's fired?

Comment: yes..inside constructor it is fired. Also using or not using ngZone is not making any difference.